# perform multiple for loops simultaneously

Tags: python, for-loop, simultaneous

Is it possible to perform multiple loops simultaneously in python.

Like(syntax error, of course):

```
for a,b in list_of_a,list_of_b:
      //do some thing
```

By *simultaneously*, I am **not** meaning the thread or process sense.

I mean, they share the same index or cursor during the iteration.

What I can think of achieving that is:

1. Use a int variable to act as a shared cursor
2. put them in a list of tuples and iterate the tuple-list. But creating the list is laborious

I am just wondering if there some built-in functions or simpler syntax to achieve that.

Comment: If what you want is nested loops instead of simultaneous loops, use `itertools.product`. If list is just the indexes of the other, use `enumerate`.

Comment: Useful tool, thanks. That's a bonus I got. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for a,b in zip(list_of_a, list_of_b):
  # Do some thing
```

If you're using Python 2.x, are worried about performance, and/or using iterators instead of lists, consider [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead of [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

In Python 3.x, [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/functions.html#zip) replaces `itertools.izip`; use `list(zip(..))` to get the old (2.x) behavior of `zip` returning a list.

Comment: Explanation: `zip` creates a list of tuples out of its arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
for a, b in itertools.izip(list_a, list_b):
    # ...
```